# Acronyms in a table environment are not shown in the list of acronyms

Tags: acro

I'm having a problem with the Acronyms' list. The acronyms mentioned in a table are not  printed in the list of acronyms.

I'm using the `acro` package and calling the acronyms with `\acs` because I only want the short format in the text. But this does not have any effect on the problem. I'm creating the list by using `\printacronyms`.

I've already tested this by placing the acronyms outside the table. In this case they're printed in the list.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{numprint}
    \selectlanguage{ngerman}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage[linewidth=1pt]{mdframed}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    
    \usepackage{acro}
    \DeclareAcronym{gesch}{
     short = gesch. ,
     long  = Geschätzt,
     class = abbrev
                          }
    
    \DeclareAcronym{tsd}{
     short = Tsd. ,
     long  = Tousend,
     class = abbrev
                          }
    \DeclareAcronym{utaut}{
     short = UTAUT ,
     long  = Unified Theory of Acceptance and Use of Technology ,
     class = abbrev
                          }                       
    \DeclareAcronym{usw}{
     short = usw. ,
     long  = Und so weiter ,
     class = abbrev
                          }

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}

\newpage
\printacronyms
\newpage

    \pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Theoretischer Hintergrund}

Test the acronyms \acs{usw}. The Theory is \acs{utaut}.

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
        \begin{mdframed}
            \begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.99\textwidth,center}
                \begin{tabular}{llccc}
\hline 
\textbf{Stadt} & \textbf{Land} & \textbf{Bevölkerungsanzahl} & \makecell{\textbf{\acs{gesch}} \\ \textbf{Nutzer}} & \makecell{\textbf{\acs{gesch}} \\ \textbf{Nutzer in $\%$}} \\ 
 & & & & \\
Poznan & PL & \numprint{530} \acs{tsd} & \numprint{450} \acs{tsd} & 84,9$\%$ \\ 
Madrid & SP & \numprint{173} \acs{tsd} & \numprint{170} \acs{tsd} & 97,8$\%$ \\ 
& & & & \\ 
\hline
\hline
& & & & \\
Berlin & DE & \numprint{222} \acs{tsd} & \emph{\numprint{173}} \acs{tsd} & \emph{80,8$\%$}  \\
& & & & \\
\hline 
                \end{tabular}
            \end{adjustbox}
        \end{mdframed}
\caption[Geschätzte Anteile]{Geschätzte Anteile (Quelle: Eigene Verarbeitung)}
\label{tabi}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is what I get (also after compiling multiple times):
[image]

while this is what I need (I get this after placing the acronyms **outside** the `table` environment as such :
`Test the acronyms \acs{usw}. The Theory is \acs{utaut}. \textbf{\acs{gesch}} \numprint{450} \acs{tsd}`):
[image]

Any suggestions how to show **all** acronyms in the list wherever they're mentioned in the document?

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the problem itself, but please don't use `adjustbox` to make a table fits into the textwidth. With this aproach you will end up with inconsistent font sized throughout your document. As an alternative, you could take a look at either `tabular*` or the `tabular` package.

Comment: Regarding the issue itself: Which version of the `acro` package did you use?

Comment: The issue is not reproducible using `acro` version 2. With this version I get the expected output in which acronyms that are only used inside of a `table` environment are included in the list of acronyms as well. If I use `acro` version 3 (3.2 to be precise), I can reproduce the issue. (Additionally, I receive 4 warnings informing about the "class" key having been replaced with the "tag" key.)

Comment: The manual of `acro`version 3.2 mentions: "In a number of contexts all acronym commands act as if their starred form is used: in the table of contents, in the list of figures, and in the list of tables. The same is true for floats and the measuring phase of common table environments like tabularx or ltxtable."  as well as "...a starred form which means “don’t count this as usage”."

Comment: Yes, I use the 3.2 version. Do you recommend downgrading? Or just using another package?

Comment: Thanks for the table tip!

Comment: Thanks @cgnieder for pointing this out. I loaded the package with the `[version = 2]` option and the list is produced as it should. Could you please add your comment as an answer so I can check it as a solution? Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better title for the question would probably be *Acronyms **used only** in a `table` environment are not shown in the list of acronyms* and a minimal example reproducing the behavior might be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{a}{
  short = a ,
  long  = the letter a
}

\begin{document}

\printacronyms

\begin{table}
  \ac{a}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This leads to an empty list of acronyms. The reason is that inside floats `acro` turns off the mechanism which marks acronyms as used.  That is because the placement of floats usually is somewhat independent from the surrounding text and otherwise acronyms might be marked as used too early. It is assumed that users use and explain the acronyms in the running text anyway.

However, unfortunately this behavior is not documented prior to v3.2a (2020/11/08) and obviously it might be preferable to users to revert `acro`'s behavior in floats. v3.2a and greater provide the option `patch/floats = true|false` to turn it off and on.  You can also use `\acswitchon` at the beginning of floats to turn the behaviour off only for certain floats (this also works in earlier versions).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{a}{
  short = a ,
  long  = the letter a
}

\acsetup{patch/floats=false}

\begin{document}

\printacronyms

\begin{table}
  \ac{a}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]